# How to test Windows Spatial Sound

Tags: windows, audio, surround-sound

Is there a simpler way of testing [Windows Spatial Sound](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/spatial-sound) rather than building and compiling https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/Audio ?

I am presuming videos like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6Rb2RKFbEI or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOz9b2nscoE are already pre-recorded with the spatial sound and not something that uses the Spatial sound APIs.